# The import org.apache.http.entity.mime cannot be resolved in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, apache, saslidemenu

After Adding slidemenu library in to my project I am getting this problem

> "The import org.apache.http.entity.mime cannot be resolved"

Please help me to solve this one.

Answer (score 2):

Download the jars from the apache commons site and add them to project.

or Add these two dependency

compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4"

compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3"

Comment: Its there. After adding slidemenu library this is happens before its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

In `MarshMallow` google has removed org.apache.* package so you have to either use a `CompileSdkVersion` less than 23 or import apache packages you need by external dependency like:

```
compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4"

compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3"
```

Comment: I am using CompilesdkVersion 17 and both jar files also. This problem started when i added that slidemenu library to my project :(

Comment: i guess u have conflicting dependency then try rebuilding and removing those jar and check

Comment: its a point . May be both slidemenu library and apache library had same name. Is that possible. Then what is the solution for that ???

Comment: u can exclude dependency from one project or import sliding as a library project and modify the conflicting dependency